# Github continously loading Activity feed

Tags: github, github-pages

Whenever I open my github from the last 2 days, it's activity feed continuously reloads and never stops.
Even if I try to commit anything, the Commit button can not be clicked as if the whole page isn't even loaded yet. There are other problems too like if I want to see insights of a repository that also show " Loading Data". Seems like github is unable to fetch data. I even logged out and then logged in again and also used other browsers too. That too didn't help.[image: hub]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I have recently installed Github Desktop, so maybe that causes some error in fetching data from the github unrelated to the condition wheather I have logged in or logged out OR whichever browser I am using in my system. So I uninstalled Github Desktop and then it worked fine.